# What's exactly happening to Charlotte Byrde in the swimming at night scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, ozark

In episode 1.09 of the TV series [Ozark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozark_(TV_series)), the character Charlotte Byrde decides to take a swim at night after trying to run away and failing at it, along with generally being lonely and previously having sex with someone who doesn't really care about her.

The scene starts out with Charlotte swimming, then suddenly seeming to panic, she goes limp, then drifts down under the water, until she suddenly moves her toes, then is able to push herself above the water. She smirks slightly to herself and swims home.

[image: Charlotte]

The scene seems to be a suicide attempt, but yet oddly she panics and possibly goes into shock or experiences hypothermia, drifts down in a way where her feet are near the bottom, gains feeling, pushes up, and then seems happy about "the thrill" of the near death experience.

But I'm not sure if that is the right characterization or if one could plan for something like hypothermia? **Is there any evidence coming from the executive producers or cast that fully explains the nature of this incident or Charlotte's motivations?**

Comment: hypothermia, surely?

Comment: there's a huge cable at her feet - at first I thought she was somehow "zapped" back to life by a power cable. but really I have no idea.

Comment: @LevenTrek thats interesting. I obviously didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a suicide attempt. I believe she simply got exhausted swimming and almost drowns accidentally. The fear of near death excites her. It may be the most genuine emotional she's experienced since arriving to Ozark or maybe it makes her appreciate being alive.

Comment: The problem I have with Charlotte is that she's kind of like Darlene. She does a lot of illogical things, like go swimming when she was reminded that it was probably too cold or steel a book for Wyatt, just to toss it out the window! 1+ though, because this is surely plausible interpretation. I'm just looking for something more definitive from writers, director, eps, or script.